# Is Domain of the function Open or closed or both open and closed

Tags: real-analysis

I have a doubt regarding open and closed property of domain.

For example,

if $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, then we all know that $\mathbb R$(Domain) is both open and closed.

Consider another example,

if $g: [0,1] \to (0,1)$, now should we consider both $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ as both open and closed or $[0,1]$ as closed and $(0,1)$ as open. Please explain.

Another example:

if $[0,1] \subset \mathbb R$ and $h:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ then should we consider [0,1] as closed set or [0,1] as both open and closed set.

Kindly express your thoughts and provide some hints.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider $[0,1]$ as a space on it's own right, not as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then it's both open and closed.

If you have a topological space $X$, the whole set $X$ is always both open and closed. If you endow $[0,1]$ with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$ and consider it as a topological space independent of the ambient set $\mathbb{R}$, then yes it is both open and closed. However, as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ it is closed and not open (w.r.t. the usual topology).

Comment: I don't think even the words mentioned in your answer will make any sense to OP.Thanks!

Comment: Well @VictorBarg you are welcome to rephrase my answer in more approachable way. However, the point is a bit delicate so I think it's not straightforward to capture in less precise language.

Comment: since the OP mentions that $\mathbb R$ is open and closed, I think that it's safe to assume that mentioning basic topological definitions is okay. Otherwise, the question should have been different: how do you define a closed set?

Answer (score 2):

Please note that saying that any set $A$ is closed or open does not make any sense,whenever one want to talk about whether a set is closed or not one have to mention the bigger space in which he is looking the openness or closedness.So the more precise statement is $A$ is closed/open in ambient space $X$.The reason of this is that every set $A$ is open in $A$ but it may not be open in any other space as pointed out by @matias.

Having said that also note that just for defining a function the domain of a function can be any set whether open or closed or neither open and nor closed.Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb R$,for defining a function you dont need to worry whether $A$ is open or closed in $\mathbb R$,for instance $f : \mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$ defined by setting $x \to x$ is a well defined function but $\mathbb Q$ is neither open nor closed in $\mathbb R$ but of course $\mathbb Q$ is open and closed in $\mathbb Q$

Comment: You're exactly right about ambient spaces. I think however, that the OP, with his/her level of knowledge as indicated by his confusion over something so basic, is likely in his first basic analysis course, where all topological concepts are introduced on $\mathbb R$. If this is indeed the case, I recommend that the OP does not look into topology on other ambient spaces other than $\mathbb R$; at least until he has a firm grounding on the basics.

Comment: @Adam V. Nease Yes u are right about my level.

Comment: @victor Barg...I think i failed to convey my question..thats what created lot of confusions...sorry about that...So just thought, by using an argument may be I can..here is my argument. Suppose there is a function $f:[0,1] \to (0,1)$ and f is onto then can f be a continuous function? we all know that  "f is continuous iff the inverse of an open set is open"  so, i am going to take the entire set (0,1) (since it is onto), (0,1) is open in R but not open in R^2 or in C, but f acts on [0,1] and (0,1) i.e no underlying spaces so that can we consider both [0,1] and (0,1) as closed and bounded?

Comment: @Victor Barg.. In short, my doubt is if $f:X \to Y$ then X and Y are both open and closed irrelevant whether X and Y are open and closed in any underlying spaces.

Comment: @SamChristopher that is an entirely different question.  The answer is that it depends on the topology. Either way, $\operatorname{Im} f=(0,1)$ can't happen since $[0,1]$ is compact. If all you care about are real analysis properties, chances are that you should restrict your attention to the euclidian topology. In which case a set $A$ is open iff for every $x \in A$ there exists some $\delta$-ball so that $B(x,\delta) \subset A$. For $[0,1]$ this is not the case, as it clearly does not exist for $0$. A set is closed if its complement is open, or if it contains all of its limit points.

Comment: ...In particular, if you take a convergent sequence of points $(x_n) \subseteq [0,1]$ is it the case that $x_n \to x \in [0,1]$?? the answer is yes. This is a different characterization of closed. Your question was really what is a closed set. Under the euclidian topology, there you have it.

Comment: @ Andreas Mejia: The function defined is $f:[0,1] \to (0,1)$ no underlying space is defined like R or C (etc)...As you suggested, [0,1] is not open, you are right only when [0,1] is subset of some underlying bigger set than[0,1]. when [0,1] is subset of [0,1] (trivial) (i.e) no underlying set, then [0,1] is open in [0,1].

Comment: @SamChristopher: Seems like you're doing first course in real analysis,i would suggest you to concentrate on **Only** on usual(euclidean) topology.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you are showing one example of a function with an open and closed domain, and using it as proof that this will always be the case for all other functions this is not how proofs work. There are lots of different functions out there.

Here's your problem:

Examples are not proofs: Let me convince you.

If your first example proves that all other functions have both open and closed domains, then why doesn't it work for your other two examples? The reason is that giving one example of a claim is not a proof for all other cases as well.

Those other functions *do not* have both open and closed domains like the first one does. For h, [0,1] contains all it's boundary points and is closed. Not every point in [0,1] is an interior point (0 and 1 aren't), therefore it is not an open set. Thus the function h is a function with a domain that is only closed. This is a counterexample to the general claim that all functions have domains that are both open and closed.

Try to see that giving one example of a claim is not sufficient proof for proving all other types of examples. You have to construct a *general argument* by proving it for the *general case*.

After you understand the previous, move on and think carefully about the following:

For a general claim, though, if you can give one example where it is *not* true, then you can prove the general claim about all the cases false. For instance, the function h:[0,1] to [0,1] is an example where the claim that "all functions have domains which are both open and closed" is *NOT* true. This collapses that general claim and disproves it.

This technique is called counter-exampling. A general rule of thumb to remember is the following:

Examples do not prove, but counter-examples always disprove.

Adam V. Nease

Comment: In other words, just because something is true in one instance, doesn't make it true in all instances. You have to *prove* that it's true for *ALL* the instances. One example is not enough to do this.